# anyway to take a 'snapshot' of alsamixer?

Tags: audio, alsa, audio-recording, pulse-audio, ubuntu-12.10

my audio card has some issues under ubuntu. everytime i fiddle with the volume, it messes up microphone.

i can't set the microphone at all under ubuntu GUI. it tries to assume things from the channels and boost and i end up with clicks instead of voice.

but i also want to keep using the GUI for volume output (as it works and is quite convenient)

so, is there any way to work around this by taking a snapshot of the mic setting in alsamixer after i set them manually, and have them replayed programatically so i can have a icon on my desktop that says 'fix mic' instead of opening a terminal, remembering what i have to change, do it manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `alsactl store` will save all mixer settings into `/etc/asound.state`; `alsactl restore` will restore them.
You can use the `-f` option to use another file; remove all entries that you don't want to change.

Alternatively, you can use the `amixer` tool to change mixer controls individually.